# Retrieving members of a group that contains a subgroup

Tags: c#, ldap

I created a dot.net form that uses c# code to retrieve members of an Active Directory group that a user selects from a drop-down, then displays the list of members (users is all I want) on the web page.

This works fine for groups that DO NOT contain sub-groups.  When an Active Directory group contains users and sub-groups I receive an error.

I only want users of the group that the users selects from the drop-down.  I don't want users from any sub-groups.

I have done lots of searching on the internet and testing various code suggestions.

```
public List<string> GetAllUsersFromGroup(string domain, 
  string group)
{
    List<string> retVal = new List<string>();
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(domain);
    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher("
     (&(objectCategory=Group)(cn=" + group + "))");

    searcher.SearchRoot = entry;
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

    var x = 0;
    var txtCN = ""; 
    var txtDispName = ""; 
    var firstItem = 0; // Display Name
    var secondItem = 1; // CN 
    var arraryResultsSize = result.Properties["member"].Count;
    string[] deResultsArray = new string[arraryResultsSize];

    foreach (string member in result.Properties["member"])
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(String.Concat(domain, 
        "/", member.ToString()));

        if (de.Properties["objectClass"].Contains("user") && 
        de.Properties["cn"].Count > 0)
        {
            deResultsArray[x] = de.Properties["displayName"]
            [0].ToString() + "~" + de.Properties["cn"]
            [0].ToString();
        }
        x = x + 1;
    }

    if (deResultsArray[0] != null) {
        string[] sortSeperatedItems = sortLDAPUsers(deResultsArray);

        for (var i = 0; i < sortSeperatedItems.Length/2; i++) {
            txtDispName = "<tr><td>" + sortSeperatedItems[firstItem] 
            + "</td>";
            txtCN = "<td>" + sortSeperatedItems[secondItem] + "</td>
            </tr>";
            retVal.Add(txtDispName);
            retVal.Add(txtCN);
            firstItem = firstItem + 2;
            secondItem = secondItem + 2;
        }
    } else {
        txtDispName = "<tr><td>Group has no members</td>";
        txtCN = "<td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
        retVal.Add(txtDispName);
        retVal.Add(txtCN);
    }

    // retVal.Add("Array Size is: " + propCount);

    return retVal;
}

public string[] sortLDAPUsers(string[] strArray) {
    Array.Sort(strArray);
    var newArraySize = (strArray.Length * 2);
    string[] itemSeperated = new string[2];
    string[] allSepItems = new string[newArraySize];
    var arrayItemsString = "";
    var xDName = 0;
    var xCName = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++) {

       itemSeperated = strArray[i].Split('~');
       allSepItems[xDName] = itemSeperated[0];
       allSepItems[xCName] = itemSeperated[1];

       arrayItemsString = arrayItemsString + "Length of allSepItems 
       is: " + allSepItems.Length + " Text is: " + 
       allSepItems[xDName] + " NetId is: " + allSepItems[xCName] + 
       "<br><br>";

       xDName = xDName + 2;
       xCName = xCName + 2;
    }

    return allSepItems;

}
```

When user selects an Active Directory group that contains users and sub-group(s), I receive the following error:

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Line 205:        for (var i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++) {
Line 206:           
Line 207:           itemSeperated = strArray[i].Split('~');
Line 208:           allSepItems[xDName] = itemSeperated[0];
Line 209:           allSepItems[xCName] = itemSeperated[1];
```

I think the error has to do with how I'm filtering or getting results in GetAllUsersFromGroup().  I don't know how to just get users from a group and not include any sub-group(s) in the results.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this filter `(&(objectCategory=Group)(cn=<group>))` is that you are querying a specific *group* to iterate and grab *all its members* regardless of the type/objectClass, so you are left with users, groups and whatever.

Instead, you can request *users that are members of this group* directly using the proper filter :

```
new DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=person)(memberOf=" + groupDN + "))");
```

Note that the `memberOf` attribute must match a DN, so given the passed in variable `group` (if the caller can't pass the actual group dn) you may have to grab it in the first place using the 1st filter.

The error you get then is another issue due to sorting, maybe comment this part until you get the proper results.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to work that hard when you could let Microsoft Active Directory do the work.

An LDAP search request with an LDAP filter to [Resolve all members (including nested) Security Groups (requires at least Windows 2003 SP2)](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+Group+Related+Searches-ResolvesAllMembersIncludingNestedSecurityGroupsRequiresAtLeastWindows2003SP2)

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

This will return all (objectClass=user) that are members of the "GroupOne".